# Java Nim Code: Why is my loop not working

Tags: java

Judging by how well known this Nim exercise is in the programming world I won't bother explaining the jist of the game.

Anyway

So I tried coding an "illegal move" parameter that denies an illegal user input of greater than half the total pile of rocks, which then loops back to ask the user to input a valid number. Problem is it isn't prompting the user to re-enter a valid input, it just goes straight to the computer's turn.

here's my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Nim {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int pile, turn, difficulty, pick;
pile = (int)(Math.random() * 90 + 10);
turn = (int)(Math.random() + .5);
difficulty = (int)(Math.random() + .5);

if(difficulty == 0)
    System.out.println("Computer is set to HARD MODE.");

else if(difficulty == 1)
    System.out.println("Computer is set to easy mode.");

System.out.println("The pile of rocks has " + pile + " total rocks. LETS GET IT ON");

while(pile>0)
{
if(turn == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Your move.");
    pick = in.nextInt();
        if(pick >= 1 && pick <= pile/2){
            pile = pile - pick;
            System.out.println(pile + "left.");}
            else {
                System.out.println("Illegal Move.");
                turn = 0;}

}

if(turn == 1 && difficulty == 1)
{
    System.out.println("Computer's move.");
    pick = (int)(Math.random()*pile/2+1);
    pile = pile - pick;
    System.out.println("Computer picks " + pick + " there are " + pile + " rocks           left.");
}
else if(turn == 1 && difficulty == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Computer's move.");
    pick = (int)(Math.pow(2,n);
    pile = pile - pick;
    System.out.println("Computer picks " + pick + " there are " + pile + " rocks left.");
}

if(turn == 0)
    turn = 1;
else turn = 0;
}
if(turn == 0)
    System.out.println("Computer: This game is for noobs.");
else
    System.out.println("Computer: Scrub.");

}}
```

As you may be able to see, it's suppose to detect the illegal move and reset the turn back to 0 prompting the user's turn again, except it's just skipping to the computer's turn. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Also I've been trying to find a more elegant way to code the 'smart' mode for the computer. My professor showed us a more sloppy way where he just took the flat amounts (perfect squares - 1) and copy pasted the value over and over for different amounts, but I want to be able to get it in a nice compact formula since it's a more elegant solution -- I'm thinking either I'm going to use the square root function or the power function but I'm unsure. Any help I could get for that would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is why every programming student should be taught to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `continue` directive after setting `turn` to 0. Try this:

```
if(pick >= 1 && pick <= pile/2){
        pile = pile - pick;
        System.out.println(pile + "left.");}
        else {
            System.out.println("Illegal Move.");
            turn = 0;
            continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `turn` to 0 is no help, because it's already 0.  You need to EITHER set it to 1 when there's an illegal move (which  is probably easiest), OR somehow skip out that chunk of code down the bottom that changes it from 0 to 1.